# Hide/Show UI Elements in while loop

Tags: loops, ios5, uiimage, while-loop

This is probably an easy one but I want to hide variably named UI elements in a loop:

```
int i = intFigures + 1;

while (i <= 16) {
   imagei.hidden = TRUE;
   i++
}
```

Essentially I need to display a number of images between 1 and 16 depending on the record. If that particular record only has 12 images, I want to hide `UIImage` 13 through 16. How do I set the `UIImage` that I am trying to hide based on the increment of the loop?

Comment: This question is really unclear. Maybe you just want an array? `image[i].hidden = TRUE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just append the variable i to the name of the image variable. You probably already have your ImageViews in an array, why not just iterate over that.

```
for(UIImageView *image in myArrayOfImageViews) {
    image.hidden = YES;
}
```

Alternatively, if your imageViews are added directly to your current view, you could just iterate over its subviews. When you add the images, you could give certain imageViews a specific tag so that you can later identify them. Such as:

```
for(UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
    if (view.tag == SOME_MAGIC_NUMBER) view.hidden = YES;
}
```